# Is there any "onchange" on navs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have nav-tabs like this :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="foo" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#navFoo">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="bar"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#navBar">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Today I use this :

```
$("a[data-toggle=tab]").on("click", function (e) {
    var whichTab = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
    //Do something
});
```

Is there any on ("navchange") or something that fires when active nav changes ? And any way to get the new active nav?

Thanks

Comment: you can check `active` class for `li`

Comment: Yeah I can do it on on("click"), but isn't there some onChange or something? I can't find any on doc

Comment: No it's not. you can't

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs-events

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $('body').on('click', 'li[class=active] a[data-toggle=tab]', function() {
       // do something
    });
```